# How to inject data from JSON to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a small project to read JSON file and insert each object into a DIV in already existed HTML. So if you check the below, I need id and class from JSON file to show up under this order:

```
"id": external-events-list "class": fc-event fc-h-event.fc-daygrid-event.fc-daygrid-block-event.fc-event-main
```

The issue is, I can't get it to work to go where I want it. Please check this JS Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON("resources.json", 
                function (data) {
            var employee = '';

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING
                // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
                employee += '<tr>';
                employee += '<td>' +  
                value.id + '</td>';  // THe ID is showing up - So like this it works!

                employee +=  '<div class="fc-event-main">' +  '<div class="fc-event.fc-h-event.fc-daygrid-event.fc-daygrid-block-event">' +
                    value.title + '</div>' + '</div>'; //But this Doesn't WORK! 

            });
              
            //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE 
            $('.fc-event-main').append(employee);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the HTML Code:

```
<body>
  <div id='wrap'>

    <div id='external-events'>

      <div id='external-events-list'>
        <div class='fc-event fc-h-event fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event'>
          <div class='fc-event-main'>Employee 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class='fc-event fc-h-event fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event'>
          <div class='fc-event-main'>Employee 2</div>

    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JSON code that I'm reading is like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "John",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Tom",
    }
]
```

Comment: It looks like in your string concatenation you haven't closed the `<tr>` and it feels like the `div` should probably be *inside* the `td`.   Also - it looks like you're trying to inject a table row (`tr`) into a bunch of divs which are *not* a proper `table`. What is "not working"?  What do you see? and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Check what's the value of of `employee` before you append it to `.fc-event-main` elements. Is that expected?

Comment: employee data show up on the page if I use <tr> but not for DIV - so employee data includes the JSON data file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell what exactly you want this script to do because you're mixing table cells with div tags and a list that appends every div with a class tag. There are many little mistakes. Here's my interpretation. Take a look. Notice I've used backticks and template literals to display the data. This makes the code cleaner and easier to read.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //  $.getJSON("resources.json",
  //   function(data) {
  let data = [{
      "id": "1",
      "title": "John",
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Tom",
    }
  ]
  let employee = '';

  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    employee += `<div class='fc-event fc-h-event fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event'>
        <div class='fc-event-main'>Employee ${key+1}</div>
      <table><tr><td>${value.id}</td>
    <td><div class="fc-event-main">
    <div class="fc-event.fc-h-event.fc-daygrid-event.fc-daygrid-block-event">${value.title}</div>
    </div></td></tr></table>
    </div>`;
  });

  //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE 
  $('#external-events-list').append(employee);
  //  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrap'>

  <div id='external-events'>
    <div id='external-events-list'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want something a little more robust and abstracted, you might find this interesting, apply to styling/classes as needed.

If working with items you might want to be adding and removing, you should work on the object then run a render function to render things, this is especially important if you're adding click events to things.

```js
let employee = (function() {

  let root, form, data = []

  function init(elm, items) {
    root = elm
    data = items

    render()
  }

  function cancel() {
    form.find('[name="title"], [name="id"]').val('')
    form.find('.add').show()
    form.find('.update, .cancel').hide()
  }

  function add(id, title) {
    data.push({
      id: data.length ? parseInt(data[data.length - 1].id, 10) + 1 : 1,
      title: form.find('[name="title"]').val()
    })
    cancel()
    render()
  }

  function edit(item) {
    form.find('[name="id"]').val(item.id)
    form.find('[name="title"]').val(item.title)
    form.find('.add').hide()
    form.find('.update, .cancel').show()
  }

  function update() {
    let id = parseInt(form.find('[name="id"]').val(), 10)
    data.splice(data.findIndex(v => v.id === id), 1, {
      id,
      title: form.find('[name="title"]').val()
    })

    cancel()
    render()
  }

  function remove(item) {
    data.splice(data.indexOf(item), 1)
    render()
  }

  function render() {
    root.empty()

    form = $(`
      <form>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" />
        <input type="text" name="title" />
        
        <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="update">✔️</button>
        <button type="button" class="cancel">x</button>
      </form>
     `)
    form.find('.add').click(add)
    form.find('.update').hide().click(update)
    form.find('.cancel').hide().click(cancel)

    let list = $('<div id="events-list" />')

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      let item = $(`
        <div>
          <div>
            Employee ${parseInt(value.id, 10)} - ${$('<span/>').text(value.title).text()} 
            <button class="delete">X</button> <button class="edit">Edit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      `)
      item.find('.delete').click(() => remove(value))
      item.find('.edit').click(() => edit(value))

      list.append(item)
    })

    root.append(list)
    root.append(form)
  }

  return {
    init
  }
})()

$(document).ready(function() {
  // $.getJSON("resources.json", function(data) {
  let data = [{
      "id": "1",
      "title": "John",
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Tom",
    }
  ]
  employee.init($('#events'), data || [])
  //})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='events'></div>
```